# Insert mode on Google Keyboard

Tags: google-chrome-os

I've just been typing HTML in a browser tab online and all of a sudden had triggered insert mode (where typing overwrites the following character) using a keyboard on a Chromebook (Chrome OS) - I had no idea how to switch it off so just had to save my draft. I never knew I had this capability and can't figure out how to get it back on. The [shortcut lists](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1047364?hl=en) online offer no hints!

I think I was playing with ctrl shift and alt but no idea what other keys unfortunately...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The search key on the chromebook (the one represented by the magnifying glass) when pressed in combination with the period key will engage and disengage overwrite.

Comment: Hmm I can see that should work (from the keyboard help overlay, never spotted that) but for some reason it's doing nothing in the address bar, or this text box… Hopefully I'll find somewhere it works! Thanks though, seems to be "the right answer"

Comment: Your welcome and I think it might be broken at the moment but I expect it will work in a future update as it was working before one of the previous updates and your welcome :)

Comment: In my case the search key was located right above the shift key on the left.

Answer (score 0):

To desactivate overtype mode (or insert mode) on French-layout keyboard:

`search key` (magnifying glass) + `.` (dot key)